# Where is the base in this logarithm?

Tags: logarithms

We are studying logarithms in our math class and I stumbled upon this task:

[image]

I am not asking for the solution of the whole problem, but, to tell you the truth, I don't understand anything in it! It looks like besides math I need to have some knowledge of chemistry in order to solve it.

Can you, at least, explain to me where the base of that logarithm is? It's neither a natural logarithm (ln), nor a common one (lg), so there should be a base. But I don't see a base there!

Besides, I don't really understand what "H raised to the power of +" would mean.

Comment: If I remember correctly, then pH is minus the base $10$ logarithm of the concentration of [H+].

Comment: The plus sign isn't an exponent.  It means that the ion is positive.  Just treat $H^+$ as a simple variable.  pH uses base-10 logs.

Comment: When I studied math, we actually used $\log$ instead of $\lg$ to mean "base $10$ logarithm".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chemists use the base 10 logarithm to define pH. $H^{+}$ is the chemical name for hydrogen ions, not a mathematical term. (Element $H$, with a positive charge from having no electrons. Also called a proton.)

Comment: It's minus base $10$ logarithm, right?

Comment: @WhatsUp indeed

Comment: @WhatsUp Or it can be what the OP stated in the problem statement. $pH=-\log_{10}[H^+]$ is the same as $pH=\log_{10}\frac{1}{[H^+]}$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Ah yes, I somehow thought that $\frac1{[H^+]}$ was the concentration.